# How can I execute php and html code with eval

Tags: php, html

How can I execute html and php at the same time with eval function ?

```
eval ("<center> this is some html </center>");
```

this code doesn't work, I probably have to change it to

```
echo ("<center> this is some html </center>");
```

but sometimes, I need to do something like

```
eval("<center> hi my name is <?php echo \$name; ?> </center>");
```

it seem a bit weird but I have a case where I should work with eval

Comment: You don't execute HTML at all; HTML is not executable code. And I have never yet come across a good reason to use `eval` in the many PHP projects I've written or maintained.

Comment: I agree , HTML is not executable code, but I was asking how to solve this problem and do something lik `eval("<center> hi my name is <?php echo \$name; ?> </center>");` , of course eval is never a good solution but in the project I'm working on it is

Comment: In my case i have a string containing both html and php and this string should be put as argument on the eval function ... now the correct answer just showed me how can I do it ... let say this is my string `$code = "<center> hi my name is <?php echo $name; ?> </center>";` all I have to do is `eval("?>" . $code . "<?php");` . The project I'm working on is a special project, I'm working on a PHP templating system. @Ed Cottrell I think the question is clear, the answer is clearer

Comment: I understand the question. That is still not a good argument for use of `eval`. It's a good argument for implementing either a true template system (using WordPress-style shortcodes, Smarty, or something similar) or a series of file includes. But all of the arguments against `eval` apply to template systems, perhaps more than in most contexts. Validation is very difficult, and using `eval` often masks potentially serious risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with html in eval() function, prepend `<?php` and append `?>` in the string passed to eval()

like so,

```
eval ("?> <center> this is some html </center> <?php");
```

and

```
eval("?> <center> hi my name is <?php echo \$name; ?> </center> <?php");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$name = 'test';
$string = '<center> hi my name is $name </center>';
eval("\$string = \"$string\";");
echo $string;
```